# Which directories are deleted in the sandbox of an App during update

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I cache some downloaded information in the NSLibraryDirectory in an App. However after a recent update the users report having problems accessing the previously downloaded content in the Library directory.

Which directories are safe to cache information over new app versions? Is there any Apple documentation on this? I couldn't find any...

thanks a lot,
e.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from [Apple Application Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18):

> Files Saved During Application Updates
>   When a user downloads an application
>   update, iTunes installs the update in
>   a new application directory. It then
>   moves the user’s data files from the
>   old installation over to the new
>   application directory before deleting
>   the old installation. Files in the
>   following directories are guaranteed
>   to be preserved during the update
>   process:
>
> ```
> <Application_Home>/Documents
> <Application_Home>/Library
> ```
>
> Although files in other user
>   directories may also be moved over,
>   you should not rely on them being
>   present after an update.

Comment: Thanks for this reference. I've been struggling with similar issues lately and suspected the sandbox root to change. It's now clear to me that I should store references to files using a path relative to the sandbox and not an absolute path.

Comment: Beware that symbolic links need to be relinked as well.

Comment: @markshiz I am facing problem with symbolic links upon app update. I googled it but was not able to find out how to relink them.Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Note, however, that /Library/Caches is not preserved across updates; it's not even backed up.